# Prove that $S_n^2-s_n^2$ is martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_i)$ be iid such that $EX_i = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}X_i = \sigma_i^2$. Let $s_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2$ and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Prove that $S_n^2 - s_n^2 $ is martingale.

My attempt:

I would show that for $Y_n = S_n^2 - s_n^2$ I have $E[Y_{n+1} - Y_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = 0$

Next I can write: $E[Y_{n+1} - Y_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = E[2S_nX_{n+1} + X_{n+1}^2 - \sigma_{n+1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$

Of course $E[2S_nX_{n+1}] = 0 $ so I have $E[Y_{n+1} - Y_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = E[X_{n+1}^2 - \sigma_{n+1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = E[X_{n+1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_n] - \sigma_{n+1}^2$.

Wat can I do now?

Comment: $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$. This allows you to write the conditional expectation as an expectation in your last line.

Comment: So $E[X_{n+1}^2 | \mathcal{F}_n] = EX_{n+1}^2 = \sigma_{n+1}^2$. Could you tell me why X_{n+1} is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$ ?

Comment: If $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$ is the natural filtration, then $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,..,X_n)$. Once $X_{n+1}$ is independent of each $X_i$ you have $X_{n+1}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro you better say independent of $(X_1\dots X_n)$. This is not equivalent.

Comment: You're right @mookid! They could be independent pairwise. But I can't change my answer anymore... =/

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro Hi, Rodrigo. How to know $E(2S_nX_{n+1}|\mathcal {F}_n)=0$? Thanks!

Comment: Because $S_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable and $X_{n+1}$ is independent with $\mathcal{F}_n$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $\mathcal F_n$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1,\dots,X_n$. It remains to show that $\mathbb E[X_{n+1}^2\mid\mathcal F_n]=\sigma_{n+1}^2$. Since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, we have $\mathbb E[X_{n+1}^2\mid\mathcal F_n]=\mathbb E[X_{n+1}^2]$.

Comment: Hi, Davide. How to know $E(2S_nX_{n+1}|\mathcal {F}_n)=0$? Thanks!

Comment: @Tuyet Since $S_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable, this is equal to $2S_n\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n]$. Since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n$, we have $\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n]=\mathbb E[X_n]$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo You mean $=E[X_{n+1}]$?